Complexity analysis depending on factors of a number
Here in this code, we have someFunc() which takes O(n) time and will be called for a factor of n times. Can anybody explain how many maximum possible factors of a particular number is possible? I checked it online and got to know that O(n*sqrt(n)) times would be the maximum possible time complexity. But how is sqrt(n) the maximum factor possible?
for(int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    if(n % i == 0 && someFunc()) {
        // do something;
    }
}



Can you please provide the source you got that claim from? Also it seems the addition of someFunc is irrelevant to your question. Couldn't you just ask about the complexity without that call?

How does n relate to len?

I referred to AI applications and asked for an explanation there it provided the information. I wasn't really clear about it.
